# cannot load images into dompdf on same server?

Tags: image, pdf, dompdf

Why cant i add images on my server to a pdf? I think it has something to do with the url structure, is it supposed to be different for this scenario?
currently its:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/images/image.jpg">
```

Comment: You're missing the equals in between the attribute and its value `<img src="http://mywebsite.com/images/image.jpg">`.

Comment: But if that's just an editing problem in the question, depending on the version of dompdf you have to set DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE to true. As far as dompdf is concerned remote is any URL of the form `http://...`.

Comment: Whoops forgot the =. Despite that I can't pull the image from the same server. I have a few servers so just pulling it from another. No idea why it doesnt work but found a cowboy fix

Comment: So it works from another server, but no from the same one where dompdf is running? That's ... more difficult.

Comment: It works fine. It would be nice to have it on the same server but its not worth going nuts over

Comment: Alright, we'll leave it there then. Going nuts over trivial issues is what I do, but it's not for everybody ;)